# Echo 05000 ? PHP

Tags: php

Could some one please Explain why echo 05000  = 2560 ???
i don't get it , i tried to search over the net i didn't find it somewhere
Thank you

Answer (score 8):

05000 is [octal notation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), 2560 is decimal notation.

Answer (score 5):

The leading `0` means that the number is in octal (base 8) rather than decimal (base 10).

5000<sub>8</sub> = **5**×8<sup>3</sup> + **0**×8<sup>2</sup> + **0**×8<sup>1</sup> + **0**×8<sup>0</sup> = 2560<sub>10</sub>

Answer (score 3):

It's a [string integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) literal in octal notation.

You can do base conversions with `base_convert`. Example:

```
echo base_convert("5000", 8, 10); //echoes "2560"
```

See [Positional notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation).