# PHP date outputting incorrect month

Tags: php, date

If I pass for example `?month=$04` in the url and echo `$date` I keep receiving January and not what it should be (April). If I echo out `$month` I get 04 which is correct. This is the code I have been using:

```
if (isset($_GET['month']) && $_GET['month']!='') {
        $month = $_GET['month'];
        $date = date('F', $month);
}

echo $date;
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why it's not outputting correctly. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Be aware that `09` might get interpreted as an [octal number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431808/echo-05000-php) depending on context. It would be a good idea to remove the leading `0` before doing any calculations with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at what you're doing here:

```
date('F', '04');
```

the second parameter to `date()` is a timestamp, starting January 1st, 1970. So what you are doing is specifying January 1st, 1970, 00:00:04 hours midnight.

What you want to do could be achieved e.g. like so:

```
$timestamp = strtotime ("2000-$month-01"); // 2000-04-01 will always be April
echo date('F', $timestamp);
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks for helping out - I know understand why as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)() with the wrong parameter. $month must be a Unix timestamp. You can consider using [mk_time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)() function.

Answer (score 0):

You need an actual date. Try something like
`echo date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0));`